# Deploying react.js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

I need some guidance on how I can deploy my ReactJS App on GitHub-Pages.

I have a GitHub account, latest version of npm and node, and of-course a react project.

But I don't want to install git on my machine.

Can I deploy my app without git?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might try using [codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces). You'll still have to use `git` but you won't have to download anything onto your machine.

Comment: I am not sure if github can help you here. But since you have github account you can link the account to vercel or netlify where you can decide which repo to be hosted (without creating the build). It takes 2-3 steps to host a website. I prefer Vercel because of unlimited bandwidth, whereas netlify has limited one. Else both are same.

Comment: You can't scape using git in this case. I think you better contact GitHub since you have an account there